Trying to get Tomcat startup errors in windows
Trying to start Tomcat 10.1 in windows x64 machine. While executing the startup.bat file inside the bin folder, one cmd screens pops up promptly and then shuts down. Unable to see the error. Also there is logs generated in log folder. How can I find out the actual error in windows.
Tried to change the logging levels in conf\logging.properties file. But still unable to get any error. I have tried with different JAVA version but still the issue is same. Please note, older version of 9.0.84 is working properly.

Try starting cmd and then cd to your Tomcat bin folder to run startup.bat. The window will stay open for you to examine the output. Note that you'll need at least Java 11 to run Tomcat 10.x

Do the logs you mention contain any information?

The startup output should be in catalina.out. Or you could try executing catalina.bat run. This should run Tomcat in console without redirecting the output to catalina.out.
